# Entity Framework Core: many-to-many relationship with the same object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've started use Entity Framework Core. I have a `User` entity:

```cs
public class UserEntity
{
    public UserEntity()
    {
        ForbiddenIngredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
        PreferredIngredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; } //UserName
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> ForbiddenIngredients { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> PreferredIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

And I have also `Ingredient` entity:

```cs
public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public string IngredientID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I want to create 2 tables which collect *forbidden ingredients* and *preferred ingredients* for each user. What should I to to make it work?

Comment: What is your version of Entity Framework Core?

Comment: @DoNhuVy Version 3.1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to normalize your DB. The first table keeps a User with a primary key UserId , the second table - Ingridient has IngridientId as a primary key and the third table UserIngridient will keep UserId and Ingridient Id as the foreign keys. All ingridient are the same, only some of them maybe forbidden for user but it maybe not forbidden for another user . So  you need a forth table - Type. But since you have only 2 types you can use a flag for this - Forbidden or Prefered. This flag should be kept in UserIngridient Table since it depends on the user and ingridient for this user.

Change your code to this:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
       
    }

    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; } //UserName
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
   
}

public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you have to ADD one more table for normalization :

```
public class UserIngredient
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

     public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }
    public int IngredientTypeId { get; set; }  // 0 or 1
   // OR   public string IngredientType { get; set; }   // Forb or Pref
.... add some virtual props  here
}
```

Comment: User have the both collections - PREF & FORB. Why to give up on one collection?

Comment: In this case you will need two classes (and two tables) PrefIngredient and ForbIngridient. It is much easier just to add flag. And I put that you need an extra table UserIngridient  for normalization. You don't want to repeate all ingridients for each user.

Comment: Tanks for halp, I have some more Q. By this solution, I'll have 3 tables? This `virtual` key-word will cause EF save the FK in the match tables?

Comment: You have to normalize your db. The first table keeps a User with a primary key UserId , the second table - Ingridient  has IngridientId as a primary key and  the  third table UserIngridient will keep UserId and Ingridient Id as  the foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution help me!

Comment: Since you are not very comfortable with EF, I highly recomend you to install "EF Core Power Tools" at your Visual Studio. You can create your DB with all primary and foreign keys and after this you can use this tools to genereate your code-first EF. It is very usefull for learning to compare your DB and your EF code. You will learn alot.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

Your database relationship designing was wrong. You should add more a field to `Ingredient` to point out `Forbidden` or `Preferred` (`tinyint` type).

Comment: But I for one USER the INGRE is preferred, and for the other its forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

Answering original question about multiple foreign keys to same table. Logic is being set up in `DbContext.OnModelConfiguring` via Fluent API.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            ForbiddenIngredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
            PreferredIngredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
        }

        [Key]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> ForbiddenIngredients { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> PreferredIngredients { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int IngredientID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual User ForbiddenUser { get; set; }

        public string ForbiddenUserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User PreferredUser { get; set; }

        public string PreferredUserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("connection string");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(x => x.PreferredIngredients)
                .WithOne(x => x.PreferredUser)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.PreferredUserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(x => x.ForbiddenIngredients)
                .WithOne(x => x.ForbiddenUser)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ForbiddenUserId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var user = new User()
            {
                Email = "test@test.com",
                ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                FullName = "name",
            };

            user.ForbiddenIngredients.Add(new Ingredient()
            {
                ForbiddenUser = user,
                Name = "forbidden",
            });

            user.PreferredIngredients.Add(new Ingredient()
            {
                PreferredUser = user,
                Name = "preferred",
            });

            var dbContext = new AppDbContext();

            dbContext.Add(user);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            var dbUser = dbContext.Users
                .Include(x => x.ForbiddenIngredients)
                .Include(x => x.PreferredIngredients)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```